# Missing Model/Database Table in a Plugin in a CakePHP project

Tags: cakephp, plugins, model

I have a CakePHP project having 3 plugins: `Plugin1`, `Plugin2`, `Plugin3`. These are simple plugins, I've just tried to split up my project into 3 smaller & easier parts.
`Plugin1` has to use a model `Model1`, where there is no `db table` for this `Model1`.

I know the `$useTable=false` thing. My problem is, I have a `function` `func()` in that model, and I am trying to use that `function` `func()` in a `Controller`, in `Plugin1`. But it shows an SQL SYNTAX error. I think, usually we use the `find()` `function` of the model, but here we are creating a function and using, may be that's the problem.

Here, table-name and Model-name are in correct convention. I don't want to create a table for this, since I don't need it. What to do now ?

Comment: What is your SQL syntax error? What code is triggering that error?

Comment: Show your model association code.